# Java guardar varios objetos en un fichero .dat

Tags: java, archivo, objeto

estoy intentando resolver el siguiente ejercicio. Tengo una clase Producto que tiene como atributos nombre, código y año de compra. (Esta clase tiene implements Serializable). Esta clase tiene un método antiguedad que devuelve true  si el año de compra es mayor a 5 años desde el año actual. La clase funciona correctamente la he probado.
El problema es que en el programa principal tengo 5 productos almacenados en un ArrayList  y sólo tengo que guardar en un fichero productos.dat aquellos cuyo año de compra sea inferior a 5 años. Después tengo que leer el fichero e imprimirlo por pantalla.
El programa rompe y no se porque. Os paso el código por si me podéis echar una mano.

```
public class grabarDatos {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
   ArrayList <Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();
   String nombre, codigo;
   int anio;
   Producto p = new Producto();
   
  //Almaceno en el arrayList los datos:
  for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Nombre producto "+(i+1)+":");
        nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Codigo producto "+(i+1)+":");
        codigo = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Año de compra del producto "+(i+1)+":");
        anio = Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine());
        p.setNombre(nombre);
        p.setCodigo(codigo);
        p.setAnio(anio);
        productos.add(p);   
    }   
    
    //Añadir al fichero
    boolean antiguedad = false;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream ("datos.dat"));
    //recorro el ArrayList con los productos y compruebo cuales tienene menos de 5 años
    // para guardarlos en el fichero
    for (int i = 0; i<productos.size(); i++){
      antiguedad = productos.get(i).antiguedad;
      if (antiguedad == false){
        ous.writeObject (productos.get(i));
        ous.close();
      }
    }

   //Leer del fichero
   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream ("datos.dat"));
   p = (Producto) ois.readObject ();
   System.out.println (p.toString());
   ois.close();
   }     

}
```

Comment: Checa tu variable ous, escribiste `ObjectoOutputStream`

Comment: Si es otro error, entonces sube el código de tu clase producto

Comment: Me sigue dando error. Es un error al copiar y pegar en el codigo lo tengo bien. 
Si solo tengo un objeto me funciona bien la clase el problema es al crear el ArrayList y guardar varios objetos en el fichero que no me los guarda.